# Bridge mode absent in new ISP routers

Tags: router, isp, bridge

In the new routers that ISP(s) provide to their clients
 
I noticed that the option to Bridge a LAN Port absent...

This routers are of known brands like:
Alcatel, Hitron, TP-Link, Netgear, etc.

It is a useful feature I always use to put one of my routers
and avoid fiddling with the ISP router configuration
except the bridge port configuration... of course.

Is there any technical or comercial reason
 
for the ISP(s) to remove this feature ??

- PS: I put at first this question in "Network Engeneering"
  but there was there a moderator dude who complain
  that this discussion was not about "Network Engeneering"...
  Elas/LOL,,,

Comment: You have to at least give us a model name/number so we can try to figure out if there's a way to configure such router in bridge mode

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking at the wrong product lines from those companies. Why pay extra for something to be a full multifunction home gateway router with integrated broadband modem, LAN switch, and Wi-Fi AP and then turn off the router functionality? If all you want is a broadband modem, buy a simple modem.

Comment: Yep, totally agree with that. +10

Answer (score 0):

ISP's often choose to hide the bridge function on modems so the WiFi capabilities can be used. By placing a router in bridged mode, the wifi is disabled too. These companies often have something like: shared wifi. If you have a connection of theirs, you can freely connect to other people's network that have the same ISP.

But for this to work, WiFi has to be enabled, and bridge mode disables that.

The ISP usually can still turn a modem into bridge mode which is great if you work with a second router behind the modem/router. You usually only have to call support and simply ask.